# React: Can I add attributes to children's resultant HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component that wraps other components:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div> {this.props.children} </div>
  }
}
```

Let's say I add another random component as a child:

```
<MyComp><FancyP>Hello</FancyP></MyComp>
```

The resultant HTML would be like this:

```
<div>
  <p class="fancy">Hello</p>
</div>
```

I know that using `React.Children` I could add new props to the child component, but what I really want to do is add custom attributes to the resultant HTML of any random child, having something like this:

```
<MyComp childAttr={{'data-x':'value'}}><FancyP>Hello</FancyP></MyComp>
```

that would generate the following:

```
<div>
  <p class="fancy" data-x="value">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Adding a props to the children does not work because children's classes are not aware of the new props and they ignore them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need this and I do recommend you to **rethink your architecture before it is too late**.

But you can do a little bit of a hackery using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`.

First you need to set refs for every child component. By cloning element and assigning a ref.

Then attach hooks on `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` events, find dom element using `findDOMNode` and manually populate dataset. [DEMO](https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/ezBGoa).

```
import React, { Component, Children, cloneElement } from 'react'
import { render, findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'

class MyComp extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setChildAttrs()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setChildAttr()
  }

  setChildAttrs() {
    const { childAttrs } = this.props
    const setAttrs = el => Object.keys(childAttrs)
      .forEach(attr => el.dataset[attr] = childAttrs[attr])

    // for each child ref find DOM node and set attrs
    Object.keys(this.refs).forEach(ref => setAttrs(findDOMNode(this.refs[ref])))
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (<div> {
        Children.map(children, (child, idx) => {
          const ref = `child${idx}`
          return cloneElement(child, { ref });
      })} </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: The main reason is because I want to use this tooltip library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip and it requires to mark the elements that will show a tooltip. I don't want to add the needed props to every component that we already have created and I was looking for a different approach. So thank you for the solution and your advice against it: I will try to find another approach first (The one that it is already working is wrapping children in a div that has the desired data attributes, but I don't like it, it also seems ugly)