# React Higher Order Components to add a custom attribute to the rendered JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a React Higher Order Components to add a custom attribute "test_id" to the view of a wrappedComonent, I need that auto-genrated attribute to do some UI testing later. but I have not find a way to achieve that.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";
const wrapTestableComponent = (ComponentToWrap) => {

class TestableComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <ComponentToWrap  {...this.props} test_id={this.props.test_id} />;
    }
}

TestableComponent.propTypes = {
    test_id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

return TestableComponent
}
export default wrapTestableComponent;
```

I've also tried the below version but I got that error: Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property test_id, object is not extensible

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";

const wrapTestableComponent = (ComponentToWrap) => {

class TestableComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        var wrappedComponentView = <ComponentToWrap  {...this.props} />;
        wrappedComponentView.test_id = this.props.test_id;
        return <ComponentToWrap  {...this.props} />;
    }
}

TestableComponent.propTypes = {
    test_id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

return TestableComponent
}
export default wrapTestableComponent;
```

Comment: what it gives you? in `ComponentToWrap` is `test_id` undefined/null?

Comment: Your first example should work fine. How do you apply the HOC?

Comment: Also note that the noop constructor function in both examples can be omitted.

Comment: here is how I use the HOC

`class MyComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (<div>{this.props.in}</div>);
    }

}
export default wrapTestableComponent(MyComponent);

<MyComponent in="foo" test_id="my_id" />`

Comment: @Hakim, have you checked with my answer? Or did you figure out the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

According to the comments we discussed below, I misunderstood the question before and I revised my answer.

[image]
The way you use in http://pastebin.com/0N9kKF73 should be the best way to do what you want.

I've tried to make a function that returns `React.creatElement()` to make a copy and assigned the extra props for `ComponentToWrap` but failed because of two main reasons.

1. React.creatElement() needs a param `type`.
2. [ReactJS supported HTML attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes)

**REF:**

1. [Get HTML tag name from React element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121680/get-html-tag-name-from-react-element)
2. [React: Can I add attributes to children's resultant HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964994/react-can-i-add-attributes-to-childrens-resultant-html)

**The revised version from your pastebin and the internet.**

```js
const wrapTestableComponent = (ComponentToWrap) => {

  class TestableComponent extends React.Component {
  
    componentDidMount() {
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.wrappedRef).setAttribute('test_id', this.props.test_id);
    }
 
    render() {
      return <ComponentToWrap {...this.props} 
        ref={() => { this.wrappedRef = this; }} 
      />;
    }
  }

  TestableComponent.propTypes = {
      test_id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }

  return TestableComponent
}

const TestComp = (props) => (<div>Here is the TestComp</div>)

const NewComponent = wrapTestableComponent(TestComp)

ReactDOM.render(<NewComponent test_id="555" />, document.getElementById('View'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Lee the main end of using a HOC is to inject automatically the test_id in the wrapped component's dom. Your revised code does not provide a solution to that need because he let's the Wrapped component add the test_id in its dom `const TestComp = (props) => (<div>Here is the Test Id => {props.test_id}</div>)`

Comment: @Hakim, The part `<div>Here is the Test Id => {props.test_id}</div>` is proving that it really got `test_id` and wrapped by two lines `WrappedComponent Start` and `WrappedComponent End`. You can do `<div {...props}>Your Component</div>` something like this.

Comment: By the way, you can check my first snippet, I don't know is that your `typo` or not. But you can see you just have to pass `id` to the wrapped component `NewComponent` and you can get `test_id` in `TestComp`.

Comment: here is how I achieved injecting a test_id attribute in the wrapped component's dom but I'm not happy with using the findDOMNode function http://pastebin.com/0N9kKF73 do you have another way to achieve that without calling that API?

Comment: @Hakim I misunderstood what you want before. And after I did some research of it. The way you used should be the correct way currently.

Comment: Thank you Lee, but I do not want to use findDOMNode function which is very expensive in term of performance since it queries the real DOM to find the wrapped component. The facebook official doc discourages the use of that function https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode that might BTW be deprecated in newer versions https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678. I'm sure that there is a proper way to inject the "test_id" attribute before mounting the wrapped component but I still struggling finding it ...

Comment: Besides, that approach will not work if ComponentToWrap is a  functional/pure/stateless component who does not support refs!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you may not do the things without using `ref`, if you did the console.log for the component, you will see reactjs returns a function. but anyway, it's also a good try for me, so I added your question a upvote.

Comment: so how can I deal with functional components that do not support `ref`? my HOC can wrap any kind of component

Comment: @Hakim You can check my example, the `TestComp` is a stateless functional component.

Comment: your code is working @Lee but I wonder if we can find a workaround of using findDOMNode which seems to be not recommended. The HOC will be used to wrap all the components of my App (very complexe one) and I'm afraid that findDOMNode will have bad impiact on its performances https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678

Comment: @Hakim yep, but I think you can not do what you want without findDOMNode currently (15.4.0) if you check what `<ComponentToWrap />` is in the HOC. According to what you said "bad impact" on its performance, why do you really want to do it? Why do you need an extra **test_id** for your UI testing? Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what are you trying to find. `ref` may do all magic for you. Actually i dont have any others idea how to add custom component. [**`fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/kysymow0/13/)

```
export function SelectWrapper(Select){
  return class Wrapper extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
      var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
      element.setAttribute('custom-attribute', 'some value');
    }
    ...
    render(){
      return <Select {...this.props} ref='test'/>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to use findDOMNode function which is very expensive in term of performance since it queries the real DOM to find the wrapped component. The facebook official doc discourages the use of that function facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode that might BTW be deprecated in newer versions github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678. I'm sure that there is a proper way to inject the "test_id" attribute before mounting the wrapped component but I still struggling finding it ...

Comment: Besides, that approach will not work if ComponentToWrap is a functional/pure/stateless component who does not support refs!

Comment: @Hakim this is a way how to fix your problem. You didn't mention whether you want to use `refs` or dont (the same about functional/pure/stateless component). if you are going to describe the whole logic probably we'll try to fix it in another way

Comment: I didn't know initially that refs may be used to solve my problem, knowing that I'm looking for a workaround to avoid using findDOMNode which seems to be not recommended by Facebook. The HOC will be used to wrap all the components of my App (very complexe one) and I'm afraid that findDOMNode will have bad impiact on its performances github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678